# iterating on next item in sublist with condition in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list which is sorted and grouped based on 2 element of sublist like below

```
[[[2178393, 'a', 'online', 0, 20], [2178394, 'a', 'away', 0, 30], [2178395, 'a', 'away', 0, 40]],[[2178389, 'b', 'online', 0, 10], [2178390, 'b', 'online', 0, 15], [2178392, 'b', 'online', 1, 25], [2178391, 'b', 'online', 1, 30], [2178397, 'b', 'away', 1, 40]], [[2178388, 'c', 'online', 0, 15], [2178396, 'c', 'away', 0, 20], [2178402, 'c', 'online', 0,25], [2178408, 'c', 'online', 1, 50]]]
```

in above there are 3 sublists that contains the lists, i want to add 5th element(4th index) from next list to present list inside the sublists. In simple adding the 5th element(4th index) of every next sublist to the present sublist.

the output should be

```
[[[2178393, 'a', 'online', 0, 20,30], [2178394, 'a', 'away', 0, 30,40], [2178395, 'a', 'away', 0, 40]],[[2178389, 'b', 'online', 0, 10,15], [2178390, 'b', 'online', 0, 15,25], [2178392, 'b', 'online', 1, 25,30], [2178391, 'b', 'online', 1, 30,40], [2178397, 'b', 'away', 1, 40]], [[2178388, 'c', 'online', 0, 15,20], [2178396, 'c', 'away', 0, 20,25], [2178402, 'c', 'online', 0,25,50], [2178408, 'c', 'online', 1, 50]]]
```

Please help me.

Comment: please post it properly . Unable to understand your required output

Comment: by editing, they meant, format the lists so we can understand what's going on. add some indentation, some new lines etc. . And then, please explain better what you are trying to accomplish, and then show us what you have tried. We aren't doing homework here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to achieve that

```
for outer in range(0,len(list)):
  for inner in range(0,len(list[outer])-1):
    list[outer][inner].append(list[outer][inner+1][4])
```

**Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: Please do not use `list` as it's a reserved keyword

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested `list` comprehension along with `zip_longest`. This takes advantage of the fact that each of the innermost `lists` just needs the last element of the next `list` to be appended to it, with the last innermost list being unchanged.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

data = [[[2178393, 'a', 'online', 0, 20], [2178394, 'a', 'away', 0, 30], [2178395, 'a', 'away', 0, 40]],[[2178389, 'b', 'online', 0, 10], [2178390, 'b', 'online', 0, 15], [2178392, 'b', 'online', 1, 25], [2178391, 'b', 'online', 1, 30], [2178397, 'b', 'away', 1, 40]], [[2178388, 'c', 'online', 0, 15], [2178396, 'c', 'away', 0, 20], [2178402, 'c', 'online', 0,25], [2178408, 'c', 'online', 1, 50]]]

expected = [[[2178393, 'a', 'online', 0, 20,30], [2178394, 'a', 'away', 0, 30,40], [2178395, 'a', 'away', 0, 40]],[[2178389, 'b', 'online', 0, 10,15], [2178390, 'b', 'online', 0, 15,25], [2178392, 'b', 'online', 1, 25,30], [2178391, 'b', 'online', 1, 30,40], [2178397, 'b', 'away', 1, 40]], [[2178388, 'c', 'online', 0, 15,20], [2178396, 'c', 'away', 0, 20,25], [2178402, 'c', 'online', 0,25,50], [2178408, 'c', 'online', 1, 50]]]

result = [[bottom_list_first + bottom_list_second[-1:] 
           for bottom_list_first, bottom_list_second 
           in zip_longest(middle_list, middle_list[1:], fillvalue=[])]
          for middle_list in data]

print(result == expected)
```

Output:

```
True
```